# upgrade mysql 5.0.x to 5.x on appserv windows

Tags: mysql, appserver

I want to upgrade my appserv mysql instalation from 5.0.x to 5.x. 
I have some tables and views relationed with various web proyects and VB.net aplications in that.

Any body can help me to do that without data loss?

Comment: Do a backup, upgrade the software, restore if data loss. This needs to be done out of hours and practised LOTS OF TIMES on a test machine so that you know what you're doing

Comment: Thanks, I know the steps (back, upd, rest), but I dont know how. How do I a backup from appserv mysql?, what i have to backup?. How upgrade?, simply install the mysql version I want, and where because in appser the mysql folder is in appserv mysql? How restore the data to the new one?

Comment: This isn't a programming problem. This is more DBA/sysadmin stuff...

Answer (score 0):

(Putting this in an answer as it's too long for a comment)

*NB - I've not used AppServ so this answer is generic*

The versions of software within AppServ appear to be old. Very old. MySQL 5.0.51b, PHP 5.2.6, Apache 5.2.8 are way behind with regards to security and features. The best thing you can do is to replace the whole stack with a newer one

If you do a quick Google search for `WAMP installer`, a plethora of available stacks are listed. The first one in the list uses MySQL 5.6.17, PHP 5.5.12, Apache 2.4.9. Again, not the newest, but much more recent and feature rich. It's also available in 32 and 64 bit versions

The first thing to do is to download a virtual machine system. ([VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) is a pretty simple one to get to grips with and runs on a variety of platforms). This is so that you can practise.

Spool up an instance of Windows (which is as close as possible to your live setup) and install your current version of AppServ and your applications which use it, take a snapshot (so you can roll back) and then work out **slowly** how to update to a new stack. Take lots of snapshots as you go.

**You need to make note of your MySQL data directories and back up your Apache, MySQL and PHP configurations**

It will take time to iron out the bugs and problems you find along the way. Do not be downhearted.

Once you have worked out how to update your stack without data loss, try your applications **on the virtual machine**. There is no point in upgrading your stack if your software is going to bomb out the second it start to run.

Once you're satisfied what all the steps you need are, roll back to the snap shot you took at the start and go through all the steps again. Then again. And keep on restoring/upgrading it until you are confident that you can do the update with the minimum of fuss and panic on the live system

I would recommend doing your update over two sessions. For both sessions, choose a quiet time to do it. Essentially, out of office hours is the best, early morning (after a good sleep) is even better.

During the first session (***SESSION-1***) the server offline, backup everything, then return the server to live. And when I say "backup everything",  I mean EVERYTHING! Take this backup and restore it to a virtual machine. Go through your steps that you worked out before on this restored version to make sure everything is going to work. Make a note of anything that is different to the steps you worked out earlier.

When you've done your testing, you can do session two (***SESSION-2***). Again, take the server offline, run a differential backup on the system and a full backup of the MySQL databases. Update your WAMP stack (using the steps you worked out in ***SESSION-1***) and bring it back online. Check that all your URLs and code still works.

After you've completed your checks, send triumphant emails to whoever needs to know, put a smug smile on your face for a job well done, pour yourself a large glass of whiskey (other drinks are available) and relax - you've earned it

Sorry that I can't give you definitive steps but I use Linux for all my PHP stacks so these steps are what I would do if I was upgrading them. I spent 3 months practising upgrading my servers then did all of them in a single night (I have separate MySQL servers so it was only the Apache/PHP side I was updating - much easier and quicker)

Hopefully some of this helps. Good luck

Comment: thank you very much for your advices. I'll try to prove all in a virtual machine and in  a year or twoo - :'( -  i'll upgrade all. LOL